# Git operations: already up to date after git fetch followed by git merge

Tags: git

I try to test the following commands: fetch and merge. In order to do that, i use the following operations :

- create two files with data in a local git folder (master branch)
- push the file to a remote branch (origin/master)
- verify that gitLab has received the file
- remove one file from the local git folder in order to create a difference between the local and the remote branch (Operation which is followed by add and commit operations)

Now, the git folder contains one file whereas the remote contains two files. So, if i make a fetch (git fetch origin:master), it must retrieve the other file from gitLab and put it into a local branch named "origin/master" which will contain the file which was previously deleted.
The operation works well. I have a new branch which is created and it is origin/master. When i select it, the deleted file appears.
Nevertheless, after a coming back to the local master branch and the launching of "git merge origin/master", i have the "already up to date" message and it doesn't retrieve the file. It is strange. In fact, the "git diff origin/master" show me the difference. I am lost.

Comment: Your description of what you did is a bit vague, at least from the point of someone being able to reproduce exactly what you did.  Please include all the Git commands you did to end up in this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as designed.

Let's say you're in branch A. Then `git merge B` does not mean "pull the files from branch B into the branch A".

It means "apply all changes that were made to B (but not A) to A".

In your case branch A is ahead of branch B: Your local `master` contains everything that `origin/master` does, plus one additional commit. Thus the list of changes that are in `origin/master`, but not in `master`, is empty.

That's why your merge is a no-op.

Comment: :Please, could you tell me if it is possible and how i could test the fetch and merge commands with gitlab ?

Comment: So, it will work if the branch which has modifications is the remote ? And it is the same thing when the local and distant have different modifications ?